# Convert video for the web

Tags: adobe-premiere

i don't know if this it´s the right site for asking this question but i will give it a try.

I have a Mac and i wonder which program is the best for convert movies?

I have .MTS files and i edit the movieclips in Adobe Premiere. I have played with the export settings but i can't get the filesize down. The finaly result is a file around 250MB and i think it's too big. I need to have the file in .mp4 format.

So i asking, wich is the best settings for exporting movies in Premire for the web?

Comment: Where's the programming? Voted to migrate to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google brought up the following thread -

http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/3/904673

I'm not too familiar with Premiere but they discuss settings regarding .mts to .mp4 conversion.

Hope this helps.